# With AutoHotKey, how to use ctrl+alt in hotkey without system seeing them as down when sending other keys?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to map <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to <kbd>delete</kbd>.  Unfortunately, when I press that combination, the system sees <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>, which naturally brings up the lock screen.

I've tried this to make the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> keys look up to the system, but it didn't work:

```
^!d::Send {Alt Up}{Ctrl Up}{Delete}
```

I've tried putting `~` and `$` in front of the hotkey, but that didn't work either.

I realize I can use `KeyWait` to wait for the modifier keys to be released:

```
~^!d::
KeyWait Control
KeyWait Alt
Send {Delete}
return
```

But then I can't repeatedly press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> to quickly delete characters.  I have to release the modifier keys between each press, which is awkward.

I realize I can simulate a forward delete with a selection to the right followed by a backspace:

```
^!d::Send {Shift Down}{Right}{Shift Up}{Backspace}
```

But that's a bit kludgy, though it does work without releasing the modifiers.  It's starting to feel like there isn't a way of accomplishing this, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try SendPlay as that creates a series of events (messages) that flow directly to the active window rather than performing their native operating system function.

```
^!d::Sendplay {Delete}
```

Doc link http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendPlayDetail

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I'm not sure why I hadn't tried SendPlay, even though the docs say "SendInput and SendPlay use the same syntax as Send but are generally faster and more reliable."